# MediaPlayer doesn't continue showing subtitle (.SRT) after pause or seekTo

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, subtitle

I'm trying to implement subtitles to videoview. I've used this example project :

```
package com.example.media.timedtexttest;
import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Locale;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnTimedTextListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.TrackInfo;
import android.media.TimedText;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTimedTextListener {
    private static final String TAG = "TimedTextTest";
    private TextView txtDisplay;
    private static Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txtDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDisplay);
        MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.video);
        try {
            player.addTimedTextSource(getSubtitleFile(R.raw.sub),
                    MediaPlayer.MEDIA_MIMETYPE_TEXT_SUBRIP);
            int textTrackIndex = findTrackIndexFor(
                    TrackInfo.MEDIA_TRACK_TYPE_TIMEDTEXT, player.getTrackInfo());
            if (textTrackIndex >= 0) {
                player.selectTrack(textTrackIndex);
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "Cannot find text track!");
            }
            player.setOnTimedTextListener(this);
            player.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private int findTrackIndexFor(int mediaTrackType, TrackInfo[] trackInfo) {
        int index = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < trackInfo.length; i++) {
            if (trackInfo[i].getTrackType() == mediaTrackType) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return index;
    }

    private String getSubtitleFile(int resId) {
        String fileName = getResources().getResourceEntryName(resId);
        File subtitleFile = getFileStreamPath(fileName);
        if (subtitleFile.exists()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Subtitle already exists");
            return subtitleFile.getAbsolutePath();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Subtitle does not exists, copy it from res/raw");

        // Copy the file from the res/raw folder to your app folder on the
        // device
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        OutputStream outputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(resId);
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(subtitleFile, false);
            copyFile(inputStream, outputStream);
            return subtitleFile.getAbsolutePath();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            closeStreams(inputStream, outputStream);
        }
        return "";
    }

    private void copyFile(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream)
            throws IOException {
        final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        int length = -1;
        while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
    }

    // A handy method I use to close all the streams
    private void closeStreams(Closeable... closeables) {
        if (closeables != null) {
            for (Closeable stream : closeables) {
                if (stream != null) {
                    try {
                        stream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimedText(final MediaPlayer mp, final TimedText text) {
        if (text != null) {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    int seconds = mp.getCurrentPosition() / 1000;

                    txtDisplay.setText("[" + secondsToDuration(seconds) + "] "
                            + text.getText());
                }
            });
        }
    }

    // To display the seconds in the duration format 00:00:00
    public String secondsToDuration(int seconds) {
        return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", seconds / 3600,
                (seconds % 3600) / 60, (seconds % 60), Locale.US);
    }
}
```

and created exactly the same implementation and it somehow works, but if i stop video and continue subtitle doesn't continue or if i seek video to some time subtitle doesn't continue too.

What i have tried:

1. Every time before `player.start()` i set `player.selectTrack(textTrackIndex);`
2. I've tried to reregister listener when i'm doing `player.start();` `player.setOnTimedTextListener(this);`

Please help i've spent 4 days on subtitle features... If you have some project example or snippet it would be nice :)

Comment: MilanNz - did you find solution ? dik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have the same problem and we must implements `OnSeekCompleteListener` even if you nothing to do into override method

it's our code:

```
@Override
    public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
}
```

and it work !!!

I hope that help you

Comment: @JosefVancura Do you have the same version. Because this issue is old so maybe the fix doesn't work anymore with the latest version. I don't remember the version used but there is probably another fix if you encountered the same issue. Good Luck.

Comment: Instead of MediaPlayer use the ExoPlayer. It is a free library provided by Google and it's very good.